# Java Help Beginner Creating random numbers that add up to specific number

Tags: java

Help Im a beginner in Java I want to create a program where i ask the user to enter a number then i give them 4 random numbers that add exactly to what they typed and it should be random every time help thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a shot at your assignment, like an honorable student, and come back if you run into any difficulty and you need assistance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any attempt to attempt a solution or search the answer with a tool such as [Excite](http://google.com) or [AltaVista](http://bing.com).

Comment: Should the numbers be integers? Which distribution should be used?

Answer (score 2):

1) Generate 4 random numbers

2) Add the 4 numbers to reach a sum

3) Input * (oneOfTheRandomNumbers / sum) = 1 of the numbers to add up to Input

4) Repeat

Though naturally, you should code it yourself. Good luck! Be careful of accuracy using floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not coding it for you, but here's the plan. You'll get random but not uniform numbers.

First generate a random number from zero to the total. Then, subtract that number from the total. Generate another random number 0-new total. Repeat for third. For the last just use the remaining total.